# get Incoming call contact name and phone number using android studio kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager

I'm trying to construct an app that requires the name and phone number of the incoming call contact.

I did research to find a solution, but all the data I found was in java and there wasn't much in kotlin.

**Code found in Java :**

```
public class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephony.listen(new PhoneStateListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
                System.out.println("incomingNumber : "+incomingNumber);
            }
        },PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
}
```

**Converted above code to kotlin :**

```
@Suppress("DEPRECATION", "DEPRECATION")
class ServiceReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    @SuppressLint("UnsafeProtectedBroadcastReceiver", "InlinedApi")
    override fun onReceive(context : Context?, intent : Intent?) {
        val tm = context?.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            tm.registerTelephonyCallback(
                context.mainExecutor,
                object : TelephonyCallback(), TelephonyCallback.CallStateListener {
                    override fun onCallStateChanged(state: Int) {
                    }
                })
        } else {
            tm.listen(object : PhoneStateListener() {
                @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
                override fun onCallStateChanged(state: Int, incomingNumber: String) {
                    super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber)
                    println("incomingNumber : $incomingNumber")
                }
            }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE)
        }
    }
}
```

I attempted to implement the above code in kotlin, my println function got executed but was like below lines!

```
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 147600208; UID 10122; state: ENABLED
I/System.out: incomingNumber :
```

I decided to put it here, so if you could please assist.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the kotlin version of this class.

```
    class ServiceReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val telephony = context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            telephony.registerTelephonyCallback(
                context.mainExecutor,
                object : TelephonyCallback(), TelephonyCallback.CallStateListener {
                    override fun onCallStateChanged(state: Int) {
                    }
                })
        } else {
            telephony.listen(object : PhoneStateListener() {
                override fun onCallStateChanged(state: Int, incomingNumber: String) {
                    super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber)
                    println("incomingNumber : $incomingNumber")
                }
            }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, and do you have any idea about retrieving Incoming call contact name using kotlin?